# How to get FB Ads Insights filtered by campaign objective

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I am trying to reproduce the Facebook Ads Manager web interface Filter-by-Objective function -- I am using v2.6 of the Marketing API to download Ads Insights data, and I have tried various variations of

```
&filtering=[{'field':'campaign.objective','operator':'any','value':['POST_ENGAGEMENT']}]
```

but nothing seems to be a valid operator for field `objective`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the operator `ANY` to `IN`?